# How to change span value inside dynamically rendered table with Django using AJAX response

Tags: html, jquery, django, ajax

So I have a website with Django. I have a products page that when I add to cart that specific item using a "Add to Cart" button, the item gets added as an order item based on the item primary key. Now I have a Cart page where I can view the specific products that are already an order item this is dynamically rendered using this piece of code:

**My cart.html page**

```
               <tbody>                        
                    {% for order in orders %}
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">
                        <div class="order-quantity">
                            <span id="order_quantity">{{order.quantity}}</span>
                                <button data-url="{% url 'add' order.id %}" class="edit-quantity" id="plus">+</button>
                                <button data-url="{% url 'subtract' order.id %}" class="edit-quantity" id="subtract">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <td><img src="{{order.item.product_image.url}}" alt="" width="70" height="70"></td>
                    <td>{{order.item.product_name}}</td>
                    <td> <span>&#8369;</span>  {{order.total_item_price}}</td>
                  </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
```

Now notice that I have an add quantity button with a data url because I wanted to change the span quantity automatically with AJAX response. Now I figured out how to console log the specific quantity when an order item is clicked for example if I click on the order item Nike, on my console I will see the order quantity but I can't figure out how to change the span text because it is dynamically rendered. Please help!
[my Cart page with the two buttons and the quantity span.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9SNn.png)

with this Jquery code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("tbody").on('click', '#plus', function() {
            var quantity =$("tbody").find("#order_quantity").text("hellooooo")

            

            $.ajax({
                url : $(this).data("url"),

                success : function(response) {
                    data = $.parseJSON(response.order)
                    console.log(data.quantity)
            
                    
                } 
            })
        })

    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use same ids for mutliple elements so change them to class selector . Then , you can use `.find()` and `closest()` to get required span reference and update its value using `.text()`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("tbody").on('click', '.edit-quantity', function() {
  var quantity = $(this).closest("tr").find("span.order_quantity")
  //uncomment ajax..on your side
  /*$.ajax({
    url: $(this).data("url"),
    success: function(response) {
      data = $.parseJSON(response.order)*/
  quantity.text(29) //data.quantity
  /*}
  })*/
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        <div class="order-quantity">
          <!--use class-->
          <span class="order_quantity">8</span>
          <button data-url="{% url 'add' order.id %}" class="edit-quantity plus">+</button>
          <button data-url="{% url 'subtract' order.id %}" class="edit-quantity subtract">-</button>
        </div>
      </th>
      <td><img src="{{order.item.product_image.url}}" alt="" width="70" height="70"></td>
      <td>Somethings..</td>
      <td> <span>&#8369;</span> 1990</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        <div class="order-quantity">
          <span class="order_quantity">9</span>
          <button data-url="{% url 'add' order.id %}" class="edit-quantity" id="plus">+</button>
          <button data-url="{% url 'subtract' order.id %}" class="edit-quantity" id="subtract">-</button>
        </div>
      </th>
      <td><img src="{{order.item.product_image.url}}" alt="" width="70" height="70"></td>
      <td>Somethings..</td>
      <td> <span>&#8369;</span> 1990</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But I'm rendering the table values dynamically not manually in HTML.

Comment: And I'm using AJAX and json as response. it's working well but I just need to update thequantity based on which button I click.

Comment: That quantity values is coming for server so just use above jquery code it should work . Also , about dynamically.. this is just demo code with dummy datas because we cannot replicate your server code here  .

Comment: thanks for the answer man! It really helped me. Now I have another issue, for the quantity to change I have to double click  the add button. How do I fix this? Srry still an intermediate Django dev here.

Comment: Double click ? Put `console.log("in")` inside your event handler see if  it prints when you click on button for first time .

Comment: yes it console logs correctly. But I have to click the add button twice for the quantity to change then it just renders correctly afterwards. When I reload the page I get the wrong quantity which is more than 1 of the dynamically rendered quantity.

Comment: I am not sure about this still learning django. You can ask new question for this so that more people can help you.